# Custom RP2040 PCB Design Check (after I biffed the first one)

Tags: pcb, crystal, rp2040

I'm looking for some feedback on a circuit board that I've designed for a RP2040-powered macro keypad. I am well aware that I'm in over my head on this one, but I'm excited about this project and am excited to learn where I'm going wrong.

I've had some PCBs fabricated based on the RP2040 hardware design guide [here](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf), and did a fair amount of research to make a strong attempt. Unfortunately, none of the five PCBs seem to be communicating with my computer. I'm kicking myself because of this:

[image]

Unless I'm double-mistaken, this is one of the best ways to ensure this crystal never works. I'm really eager to make my next attempt (and purchase) a success. I'd appreciate anyone that wouldn't mind donating some time to take a look at my current design. Here's the schematic I'm working on (let me know if another format is better:)

[image]

My specific concerns here primarily revolve around the resonance capacitors with the (now hopefully-correctly-oriented) crystal. The crystal I am using is [this one](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Yxc-X322512MSB4SI/C9002). It is a 12 MHz crystal with a load capacitance of 20 pF and a max equivalent series resistance of 80 Ω. I understand that resonance capacitors around 40 pF might be more reasonable than the 22 pF ones I've chosen solely off of the advise of a seemingly-confident gentleman on YouTube that used the same crystal, but I'm not sure how precise I need to be. Additionally, the 1 kΩ XOUT resistor value isn't one I'm confident in.

Here's my PCB design in its current state (and a version without the shaded copper fills for possible ease of interpretation:)

[image]

[image]

On one hand, I feel like I did a good job with the layout. On the other hand, I don't. My main concerns here revolve around the crystal layout (bottom right) and the D+ and D- traces from the USB port (the center two of the 8 pins on this socket.)

I feel that my decoupling capacitors are sufficiently close to the power pins (based on the hardware design guide.) I believe that I've done well to leave undisturbed ground planes underneath the differential signals from the USB port, as well as underneath the crystal.

In terms of my crystal-related concerns, I'm not sure how precisely the XIN and XOUT traces need to be routed, both absolutely and relative to one another. I'm not sure how to factor in the presence of a resistor on XOUT that doesn't exist on XIN.

My concerns about the USB data lines stem primarily from lack of understanding. Additionally, my poor choice in USB-C ports left me with the need to flip the order of the traces. I think I was clever by using the already-required resistors to do a little hop, but I wouldn't know if I've made a devastating mistake.

I am including all of my thoughts because I want to show that I've put in effort to understand what is going on, even if that only means I can narrow down which of my confusions is most important. I'm open to any and all suggestions and criticisms.

Comment: Since you already made boards with 
a small error in crystal connections, did you even try to solder off the crystal and re-solder it back on at a 90 degree angle or by addind some few millimeter wires to make correct electrical connections? Why do you have 5k1 resistors on USB data wires? Why there are 2 resistors instead of just one on SPI button?

Comment: The ground loops on those decoupling caps are huge since you cut the ground under them with traces.

Comment: @Justme I'll go ahead and attempt to re-solder the crystal the right way around. Great catch on the USB resistors! They're supposed to be 27.4 ohms and I fumbled that somewhere along the line. The two 5k1 resistors were intended to save cost on the BOM and serve as a ~10k pull-up resistor. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks! I didn't make the connection that the grounds on the decoupling capacitors need to be close to the _chip's_ ground and not just to _any_ ground. I'll try to reroute!

Comment: Any reason you're using 2 layers? 4 is a lot easier and barely more expensive in small volumes. 2 requires more experience since you don't have real planes and must think carefully about how to route return signals rather than just dropping down to a ground plane. For example, you're routing a signal line under the USB lines (where some of their return current will flow) which you could have avoided. On 4 layers you don't even have to think about that.

Comment: @user1850479 I think I’ll take that advice and move towards a 4-layer design. Thank you. A question about those USB data traces: does my trick of using the resistors to swap the traces seem reasonable?

Comment: It's an impedance discontinuity since the return current from one line is interrupted by the other. For low speed USB it's not a big deal, but for usb3 you'd probably avoid that. Any reason you don't rotate the connector so the pins are in the right order?